# How to parse multiline file and do some operation for each token line in bash?

Tags: bash, csv

say we have a tsv file

```
1    2    3
1    2    3
```

we want to do some operation say `echo $1 $2 $3` for each tsv file line.

How to do such thing in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can make it:

```
while read -r a b c
do
   echo "first = $a second = $b third = $c"
done < file
```

#### Test

```
$ while read -r a b c; do echo "first=$a second=$b third=$c"; done < file
first=1 second=2 third=3
first=1 second=2 third=3
```

As the separator is a tab, you don't need to use `IFS`. If it was for example a `|`, you could do:

```
$ cat file
1|2|3
1|2|3
$ while IFS='|' read -r a b c; do echo "first=$a second=$b third=$c"; done < file
first=1 second=2 third=3
first=1 second=2 third=3
```

Comment: You probably ought to set IFS anyway in case the data might contain spaces.

Comment: Well, if it contains spaces then they will be treated as different arguments.